# Kickplate or grout first?

Tags: kitchens, floor

I have small, decorative tiles just in front of my kitchen cabinets. However, my cabinets sit on a 2x4 platform to raise them and I need to put in a kickplate to cover the wood. Should I grout first or install the kickplate first? Please help me create a tag that would cover the kickplate.

Comment: This question as it stands is impossible to answer.  Possibly a picture might help, but as is I’ve got to say there’s not enough info to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Always grout first, clean up, then install the kickboard.